# Replace product "on backorder" to a custom field value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

Firstly, thanks for viewing this question.
I've searched and gone through many similar questions however i've not managed to find a perfect fix.

Im setting up a website using wordpress/woocommerce, however most of our products have a set lead time therefore everything is on "back order - allow" status. Instead of showing "on backorder" on each product page, I wanted to see if it was possible to create a custom field in each product and replace the "on backorder" text to show that custom field.

Currently, i've been using the following code that just changes the text for every product however, not all products are on that specific lead time.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'backorder_text', 10, 2);
function backorder_text($available) {
 return str_replace('Available on backorder', 'Approx lead time: 2-4 working weeks', $available);
}
```

I appreciate I would need to set up a custom field in each product with the set time, but i'm not entirely sure how to link that specfic custom field per each product to that php code (or rather, whether its actually possible).

Any help would be fantastic - even if its to tell me it can't be done!

Comment: You can use ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin for displaying text field on every product back-end  and call that field using get_field('name'); in front-end. you can also modified that field according to your need.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-for-woocommerce-product/

, https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-advanced-custom-fields-single-product/

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am installing ACF now. Do you have any idea what the amended php would be going from the one above? 
(I lack php knowledge, learning slowly)

Comment: I tried the two php codes that you provided but both producted fatal errors. I'll look into it more and see if I can find anything online as i'd love to get this working.

Thanks for taking the time to look into it and assist though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with the following code, that will handle products and product variation too:

```
// Add a custom field in admin product edit pages - inventory tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_stock_fields', 'add_product_options_stock_custom_field', 20 );
function add_product_options_stock_custom_field() {
    global $product_object, $post;

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_backorder_text',
        'type'        => 'text',
        'label'       => __( 'Backorders text', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description' => __( 'Backorders text. Add a custom backorders text to be displayed when products are on backorders.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
    ) );

    // jQuery: HIDE the fied if backorders are not enabled
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var a = 'select#_backorders',
            b = 'p._backorder_text_field';

        if( $(a).val() === 'no' )
            $(b).hide();

        $(a).on('change blur', function(){
            if( $(a).val() === 'no' )
                $(b).hide();
            else
                $(b).show();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Save the custom field value from admin product edit pages - inventory tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_product_options_stock_custom_field', 20, 1 );
function save_product_options_stock_custom_field( $product_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['_backorder_text'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_backorder_text', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_backorder_text'] ) );
}

// Variations: Add a custom field in admin variation options inventory
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_inventory', 'add_variation_settings_fields', 20, 3 );
function add_variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation_post ) {

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_backorder_text'.$loop,
        'name'          => '_backorder_text['.$loop.']',
        'value'         => get_post_meta( $variation_post->ID, '_backorder_text', true ),
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __( 'Backorders text', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Backorders text. Add a custom backorders text to be displayed when products are on backorders.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-first',
    ) );
}

// Variations: Save a custom field value from admin variation options inventory
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );
function save_variation_settings_fields( $variation_id, $i ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['_backorder_text'][$i] ) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_backorder_text', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_backorder_text'][$i] ) );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_on_backorder_text', 10, 2 );
function custom_on_backorder_text( $availability, $product ) {
    $backorder_text = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_backorder_text', true );

    if( $availability['class'] === 'available-on-backorder' && ! empty( $backorder_text ) )
        $availability['availability'] = $backorder_text;

    return $availability;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

For all products (except variable products, see after) you will get:

[image]

[image]

For product variations *(of a variable product)*:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I modified @LoicTheAztec code slightly to use this for displaying the backorder text on the front end.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'customize_availability_text', 10, 2);
function customize_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
$backorder_text = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_backorder_text', true );
 if (! empty( $backorder_text )){$availability = str_replace('Available on backorder',  $backorder_text , $availability);}
return $availability;
}
```

Note that I'm using the

```
woocommerce_get_availability_text
```

filter
rather than the

```
woocommerce_get_availability
```

filter

This worked with my products with variations, not tested on simple products

Answer (score 0):

> The code works perfectly for simple products. But for the variations
> the back order text is available but it does not display on the
> product page when a customer makes the selection

I tried this code which seems to work for products with variation.

```
function custom_backorder_message( $message, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_on_backorder() ) {
        $message = "My text...";
    }
    return $message;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_backorder_message', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).